# Python: Copy files from a folder to another that created 2 days ago

Tags: python, file, copy, compare

I want to copy the files that have been created two days ago from a folder to an other.

This is my code:

```
src = '/home/user'
dst = '/var/tmp/backup_tmp'

two_days = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)
filetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(path.getctime(src))

for file in os.listdir(src):
  if file not in os.listdir(dst) and os.path.isfile(file):
    if filetime <= two_days:
       print "File is more than two days old"
    else:
       shutil.copy(os.path.join(src, file), dst)
```

I do not have any errors when I run the script but the files not copy to my destination folder.

Can you help me to find where is the wrong with this???

BRs,
Spyros

Answer (score 1):

You calculating filetime outside if the loop. Seems like this is a your problem. Try:

```
for f in os.listdir(src):
  filetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(path.getctime(os.path.join(src,f)))
  if f not in os.listdir(dst) and os.path.isfile(f):
    if filetime <= two_days:
       print "File is more than two days old"
    else:
       shutil.copy(os.path.join(src, f), dst)
```

Comment: Now I take this when I run the script:

if f not in os.listdir(dst) and os.path.isfile(f):
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Forgot one of the parentheses in previous line. Fixed.

Comment: You had right about the last parentheses. I run the new script and I have the same situation as I was described. No error and no copy the files.

Comment: I put to print a comment between the "for" and "if" statement and seems that not enter in the first "if"
Inside the "src" there are several files that satisfy the statement.
Any suggestions about that?

Comment: try to print `os.listdir(src)` in the begining of this code. something strange is going on.

Comment: when I print the "os.listdir(src)" I take all the files that store in the path:
['test3', 'test2', 'test', 'test0', 'test1']

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the statement:
"if f not in os.listdir(dst) and os.path.isfile(f):"
When I removed it everything works properly.

BRs,
Spyros